# How to let a non-root process in a Linux docker container bind to a <1024 port?

Tags: docker, root

Any ideas on how to let a non-root process in a Linux docker container bind to a <1024 port?

setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' won't work on aufs and I would like people to be able to use my dockerfile with any storage driver.

I can of course just listen on a >1024 port in the container and map a privileged port on the host to it, but I'm still interested if there's a way to really do it in the container.